# Strict standards: Declaration ::postDispatch()

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, strict

I want to configure Doctrine 2.2 with zf 1.11. Everything is done, but I dont know what this error is about:

> Strict standards: Declaration of Sc\Resource\EntityManagerFront::postDispatch() should be compatible with that of Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::postDispatch() in D:\xampp\htdocs\sc\library\Sc\Resource\EntityManagerFront.php on line 26

My code:

```
    <?php


namespace Sc\Resource;
use Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract, Zend_Controller_Front;

class EntityManagerFront extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

  /**
   * Flush the EntityManager.
   *
   * (non-PHPdoc)
   * @see Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::dispatchLoopShutdown()
   */

  public function postDispatch($request)
  {

    $bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
    $em = $bootstrap->getResource('EntityManager');
    $em->flush();

    return $em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final fixed solution :

```
<?php

namespace Sc\Resource;

use Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract,
    Zend_Controller_Front,
        Zend_Controller_Request_Http,
        Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract;


class EntityManagerFront extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    /**
     * Flush the EntityManager.
     *
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::dispatchLoopShutdown()
     */
    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {

        $bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
        $em = $bootstrap->getResource('EntityManager');
        $em->flush();

        return $em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The signature of postDispatch function is

```
public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
```

So you have to specify the `$request` parameter type: `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Sc\Resource\EntityManagerFront::postDispatch() must be an instance of Sc\Resource\Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract, instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Http given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\sc\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 333 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\sc\library\Sc\Resource\EntityManagerFront.php on line 18

Comment: solved with putting this in use : Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract